# How to update buttons status when the user reopens the app? (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have a question about saving the last status of the buttons for a "Hung Person" game. By using `UserDefaults` I was able to save almost all the status of the user when the game was closed (Screen1 shows the user's game status while playing), as you can see, the user chose 2 wrong letters that were not in the hidden word (M and N, which are in red and disabled) and the user correctly guessed the O, B, C letters (which disappeared from the alphabet and also are disabled).

[image: Screen1]

When the user closes the app and when it is reopened again, I was able to reload almost all the previous data of the last session played, except for the buttons status. You can see this in Screen2. I used `UserDefaults` to save and load the game. I save the status of the game every time the user taps on any button (trying to guess the hidden word's characters), and I load the data back in `viewDidLoad()`.

[image: Screen2]

The game is made programmatically, I created the buttons using something like the following:

```
for row in 0..<5 {
        for column in 0..<6 {               
            if counterLetter < 26 {
                let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: titleLabelFontSize)
                letterButton.setTitle(englishAlphabet[counterLetter], for: .normal)
                letterButton.isHidden = false
                letterButton.isEnabled = true
                letterButton.alpha = 1
                letterButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .disabled)
                letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                letterButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
                letterButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

                // Button's frame creation
                let frame = CGRect(x: column*widthButton, y: row*heightButton,
                                   width: widthButton, height: heightButton)
                letterButton.frame = frame

                buttonsView.addSubview(letterButton)
                letterButtons.append(letterButton)

                counterLetter += 1
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }
```

It is in the `letterTapped` method (inside the `#selector(letterTapped)` part in the previous code) where I save the user's progress when any alphabet button is tapped. As I said before, I recall the player's last status in `viewDidLoad()`.

I tried to save the buttons status inside the `letterTapped` method as well, but I haven't been able to save or reload the buttons status as the player's had.

Can you give me please a hand about where I have to use `userDefaults` to save the last session status of the alphabet buttons, please? So that when the players reopens the app, the screen2 is the same as screen1.

If you need me to share my code, I can do willingly it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Comment: use User Defaults

Comment: I'm already using it. But I don't know where to use it for the buttons. I explained it in the question I asked.

Comment: Save the status along with the button title (the letter) in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a K.V.O called "UIApplicationWillEnterForeground" and "UIApplicationDidEnterBackground"

In your viewDidLoad of your ViewController you should do the following:

```
func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let notificationCenter =  NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

then implement these function in the same ViewController:

```
func appMovedToForeground() {
    print("Application moved to Foreground!")
}

func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("Application moved to Background!")
}
```

now when your app goes to the background or returns to the foreground those functions will get called